# ForeignKey de duas tabelas em Django

Tags: python-3.x, django, tabela-banco-de-dados, chave-estrangeira

Fala, Povo!

Tenho o seguinte problema:
Estou desenvolvendo um sitema para uma loja que tambem realiza serviços.

Entao tenho a Tabela de Compras e Vendas (SaleOrBuy) e a tabela de Serviços(Service)

Para a SaleOrBuy criei uma tabela para armazenar os itens do carrinho (CartItem) que recebe o id da venda ou compra do produto e a quantidade.

A questão é que nos Serviços tambem há a possibilidade de se incluir produtos(como os necessários para execução do serviço)

Minha pregunta é:
Teria alguma forma no Django de colocar mais de uma tábela no ForeignKey? EX:

```
class CartItem(models.Model):
    opid = models.ForeignKey(SalesOrBuy or Service, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

A principio Tinha pensado na criação de uma nova tabela porem acho contra-produzente já que essa nova tabela seria exatamente a mesma coisa que a CartItem só que para os serviços.

Em seguida pensei em deixar o campo como um inteiro, criar um campo choice e fazer o link via código.

mas gostaria de saber se já há algo no próprio framework algo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existe a possibilidade de uma tabela conter mais que uma chave estrangeira mas não de uma única chave estrangeira referenciar mais que uma tabela, o que você pode fazer é criar mais uma propriedade(uma chave estrangeira), desse modo tu podes colocar quantos relacionamentos forem necessários.

> Uma chave estrangeira é um campo, que aponta para a chave primária de outra tabela ou da mesma tabela. Ou seja, passa a existir uma relação entre duplas de duas tabelas ou de uma única tabela

```py
class CartItem(models.Model):
    opid = models.ForeignKey(SalesOrBuy, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    service = models.ForeignKey(Service, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```